# Pandas df.reindex() doesn't work for level>0 for MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, reindex

I've got two DataFrames A and B, both with a MultiIndex in the columns. B however has the order of the columns switched up. Now I would simply like to get the columns of B in the same order as in A.

The clue is, the order depends on the second level of the MultiIndex. Pandas' `reindex()` should do just that, but it does only work for me at level 0 as shown in the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["a","b","c"], ["aa","bb","cc"]])
print(df)
```

outputs

```
    a   b   c
    aa  bb  cc
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
```

First level of the MultiIndex:

```
df = df.reindex(columns=["b","a","c"], level=0)
print(df)

    b   a   c
    bb  aa  cc
0   2   1   3
1   5   4   6
```

Second level:

```
df = df.reindex(columns=["bb","aa","cc"], level=1)
df
    a   b   c
    aa  bb  cc
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
```

The function doesn't raise an exception. And I've also tried it with `columns=["bb","aa","cc"], level=2` or `columns=["bb","aa","cc"], level=0`. There it outputs an empty DataFrame, so my implementation seems to be correct, but just nothing happens...

The next best workaround I can think of is changing level 1 to level 0, but that shouldn't be necessary. Looking forward to your ideas!

Comment: Indices are hierarchical. After you re-index your data still reflects the order of the top level index because that one hasn't changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reindex both levels, just pass your MultiIndex:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["a","b","c"], ["aa","bb","cc"]])

B = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["b","a","c"],
                                                    ["bb","aa","cc"]]),
                 index=[0])

out = A.reindex(columns=B.columns)
```

Or maybe you just want to [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
order = ["bb","aa","cc"]
out = A.sort_index(level=1, axis=1,
                   key=pd.Series({v:k for k,v in enumerate(order)}).get)
```

Output:

```
   b  a  c
  bb aa cc
0  2  1  3
1  5  4  6
```

Comment: maybe `key=order.index` works as well for not-so-wide dataframe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your application of `reindex()` works. But for understanding, my implementation should work as well, or?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes it does but it has quadratic complexity so I prefer to never give such shortcuts, we never know who will read this and reuse the code ;)

Comment: @Nicoleue `reindex` indeed behaves differently with single and MultiIndexes.

Comment: I now need the second option as well, as I have different levels in different DataFrames, that only share the second index level. So the extensive answer is much appreciated(:

Answer (score 0):

assign back to df

```
df = df.reindex(columns=["b","a","c"], level=0)
df = df.reindex(columns=["bb","aa","cc"], level=1)
print(df)

   b  a  c
  bb aa cc
0  2  1  3
1  5  4  6
```

Comment: Try only the second line without the first, doesn't do anything.